# How to implement calendar with repeatable events?

Tags: python, django, database-design, data-structures, django-models

I am trying to implement a calendar with repeatable events.
Simple example (in human language) is: 'Something happens every working day between 10:00 and 12:00'

What is the most correct way to store this data in the database and to search between them.
The search may be something like "Give me all events on Tuesday 21th of Feb 2012".

I am planning to use relational database to store them.

P.S. I am planning to use Python and Django so existing libs can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to think about how you want to implement this when determining the best way to store the data:

- should users be able to reschedule or remove one of the recurring events
- similarly, should changes to recurring events change all events or only future events?
- do you care about creating a lot of records in the database?

If the answer is yes to the first two and no to the last, the easiest way to implement this is to allow events to have a parent event, and then to create a separate record called Recurring which relates how a base event recurs. Then each time the recurring event changes, a script is triggered that creates/recreates the events.

Searching for the events becomes simplicity itself: since they are actual events, you just search for them.